# My app on Google Play doesn't show up for everyone

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have an android app. I put it on Google Play, it's already in "Available on Google Play" status. I can see it from several phones, but not from others.

Those phones have android 12, the app has minSdkVersion set to 27, maxSdkVersion is not set. The phones it doesn't work on are Samsung Galaxy A41 and Xiaomi A3. Why can't I see it from them? What should I check? Thanks.

Comment: How much time has passed since it has been marked as "Available on Google Play"? In my experience, it will need some time to be really available to everyone. Like, a few days, not weeks.

Answer (score 0):

For the apps I have on the play store, the Android minimum version will limit who can see it on the store. The phones won’t have access to your app if they don’t have the necessary platform version. It looks like in your case the only phones with Android 8.1+ will be able to download your app.

See this link for more info:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

Comment: No, I have android 12 and I can see the app. It is minSdkVersion, not exactly_this_SdkVersion.